# Как вывести значение из базы в кодировки utf8?

Tags: php, mysql

Как вывести значение из базы в кодировки utf8? Вот код которым вывожу сейчас.

```
if($number) {  
     $query = "SELECT * FROM user";  
     $result = mysql_query($query);  
     $r = mysql_fetch_array($result);  
     $n = $r['id_vk'];  
     if ($n == $id); {  
         echo($n = $r['Name']);  
     }  
}
```

Comment: SET NAMES UTF-8 перед началом запросов пробовали? Хотя советуют использовать [mysqli_set_charset](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.set-charset.php)

Файлы сохранены в UTF-8? А в какой кодировке отдаете страницу?

Comment: Данные в базе в utf8 страница тоже

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да достаточно будет:

```
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');
if($number) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM user";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $r = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $n = $r['id_vk'];
    if ($n == $id); {
        echo($n = $r['Name']);
    }
}
```